# Странный цикл for и значение y в итоге

Tags: c++

Ребят, подскажите, какого буде значение переменной y после выполнения кода:

```
int x=0,y=0;
for (++x;++x;++x) y+=++x&1;
```

Пытался отследить отладчиком в с++ билдере, `у` у меня возрастал, но после значения в 10000000 в билдере очищается окошко, где выводятся текущие значения переменных.

Comment: Что-то мне подсказывает, что UB

Comment: Что такое UB?

Comment: Undefined behavour  -неопределенное поведение, т.е. ход выполнения не определяется стандартом, а зависит от конкретной реализации компилятора, от платформы и т.д.

Comment: @Никола Кривошея, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 4):

gcc 4.9 при уровне оптимизаций `-O2` оставляет только пустой цикл:

```
.L2:
jmp .L2
```

и говорит: `warning: iteration 715827882u invokes undefined behavior`. Разберем почему.

Понятно, что компилятору все равно, что там в каждой из трех частей записано. Главное, чтобы оно выполнялось и второе выражение возвращало результат, который можно было бы проверить на истину/ложь.

Поэтому, в каждой итерации цикла, переменная x будет увеличиться на 3 (первый раз третьим выражением, потом телом цикла и третий раз - вторым выражением в for).

Умножив 715827882 на 3 и переведя в hex, получим 0x7FFFFFFE - то есть почти максимальное положительное число, которое можно записать в 32-битную переменную. Следующая итерация привет уже к отрицательному числу в x. Теоретически, увеличивая дальше это отрицательное число, можно прийти к нулю.
Но на самом деле компилятор видит, что переменная `x` увеличивается, а переменная, которая была равна нулю и постоянно увеличивается, не может быть равна нулю. Поэтому тело цикла и будет исполнятся "бесконечно" при данной оптимизации.

Итого. Какой же правильный ответ?

Если рассчитывают на то, что компилятор туп, и нужно аккуратно пройти через переполнение, то ответ прост. Это 0xFFFFFFFF / 3 = 1431655765. (при условии, что int - 32 битный).

Если у компилятора 16-битный int (старый турбо си), то ответ будет, скорее всего, 21845.

Но, возможно, что int длиной 64бита...

Но вышеприведенные ответы правильны, если компилятор не сделал оптимизаций. Если он сделал, то правильный ответ никогда не будет выведен, так как там бесконечный цикл.

Если бы меня спросили подобное на собеседовании, то я спросил бы: "А у вас тут такой код пишут?". В случае позитивного ответа, я бы встал и пошел на выход. Потому что лучше не вмешиваться в подобное. Если люди вменяемые, то они остановят и извинятся.

Comment: Для меня это очень странный оптимизационный ход от компилятора.

Comment: абсолютно нормальный. В коде сказано - увеличивать переменную. Переменная, которая постоянно увеличивается и изначально была больше нуля, не может быть равной нулю (я говорю об обычной школьной математике).

Comment: Это да, но ведь я то знаю, что есть переполнение и можно на нем сыграть. По стандарту никакого UB нету. А тут компилятор мне обрезает такую возможность на корню при данной оптимизации. Конечно, может быть так и задумано у него, но надо быть осторожным во флагах тогда.

Comment: Я тоже считаю, что это (компилировать предопределенное переполнение в бесконечный цикл) ошибка компилятора (или его авторов) и не вижу никакого UB.

--

Кстати, если код чуть изменить:


      volatile int x=0; // добавим volatile
      int y = 0;
      long long l = 0;  // исключительно от любопытства
      for (++x; ++x; ++x, ++l) 
        y += ++x & 1;

то он компилируется в непустой цикл (в том числе и при -O2) и через некоторое время можно увидеть, что после 2863311530 оборотов `x` все-таки  обнуляется, а `y` возрастает до 1431655765 (как и ожидалось -- половина от числа оборотов).

Comment: @avp: ЕМНИП знаковое переполнение есть UB. gcc, возможно, доопределяет это до сложения по модулю размера слова, но на платформах с представлением целых чисел в недополнительном коде [могут появиться проблемы](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18195756/276994).

Проблема здесь не в компиляторе, а в стандарте. Игнорирование возможного переполнения при компиляции (то есть, UB) позволяет в некоторых случаях опускать проверки и тем самым генерировать более оптимальный код.

Comment: @KoVadim, "я бы встал и пошел на выход". 

Это самое первое, что пришло мне в голову, когда я прочел задачу.

Comment: @VladD, ну, компилятор-то каждый раз делает код для *конкретной* платформы.

Поэтому для Кнутовской MIX -- UB (и отказ что-то генерировать) это правильный ответ, а для машин с традиционной двоичной арифметикой -- ошибка.